# How to find modx snippet for cache?

Tags: php, modx

Modx generate error in log. How to find original snippet in modx administation panel?

> [2019-01-18 13:30:25] (ERROR @
>   ../site/core/cache/includes/elements/modsnippet/105.include.cache.php
>   : 26) PHP warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> modsnippet/105.include.cache.php : 26

This is the key - please open snippet with ID=105 and find row № 26

In other words you need 
[/manager/?a=element/snippet/update&id=105](http:///manager/?a=element/snippet/update&id=105)